# Keras: Custom layer without inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to implement a Keras custom layer without any input, just trainable weights.

Here is the code so far:

```
class Simple(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
       self.output_dim = output_dim
       super(Simple, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
       self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', shape=self.output_dim, initializer='uniform', trainable=True)
       super(Simple, self).build()  

    def call(self):
       return self.kernel

    def compute_output_shape(self):
       return self.output_dim

X = Simple((1, 784))()
```

I am getting an error message:

`__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'`

Is there a workaround for building a custom layer without inputs in Keras?

Comment: You must call `X = Simple((1, 784))` and not `X = Simple((1, 784))()`

Comment: I want to get the output tensor, not just create the layer.

Comment: You can do `def call(self,x):` `return self.kernel(x)` and still call `X = Simple((1,784))` and continue with what you want to do

Comment: Simple((1,784)) is just an initialization. So, it creates the layer but it does not compute anything.

Comment: In order to compute you must begin training, like so:`model = Simple((1,784))` `for x,y in train_dataset:`
        `with tf.GradientTape() as tape:`
            `ypred = model(x)`
            `loss = loss_object(y, ypred).....`

Comment: Sorry, but computing the output of a neural network has nothing to do with training!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190447/discussion-between-nairouz-mrabah-and-george).

Comment: @nairouzmrabah, was there a resolution to this?

Comment: @adalca No, I don't think so.

Comment: @adalca check the answer posted by thushv89 if you are not set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class Simple(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
       self.output_dim = output_dim
       super(Simple, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shapes):
       self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', shape=self.output_dim, initializer='uniform', trainable=True)
       super(Simple, self).build(input_shapes)  

    def call(self, inputs):
       return self.kernel

    def compute_output_shape(self):
       return self.output_dim

X = Simple((1, 784))([])
print(X.shape)
```

Which produces

```
>>> (1, 784)
```

Answer (score 0):

Small correction: You need square brackets around self.output_dim:

```
def build(self, input_shapes):
   self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', shape=[self.output_dim], initializer='uniform', trainable=True)
   super(Simple, self).build(input_shapes)
```